# How do I find horizontal vertical and diagonal correlation coefficients in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, encryption, correlation, steganography

I have an image which has been encrypted, and then hidden in a cover image. and finally retrieved. I'd like to find the horiz, vertical and diagonal correlation coeff's of the initial image, and the cipher image. What's the matlab command for this?

Direction of Adjacent pixels         Plain Image        Cipher Image

Horizontal                                  0.9791  0.0052
Vertical                                    0.9357  0.0539
Diagonal                                    0.9183  0.1141

Yes they are numbers. The correlation coeeficient, which is a number, which gives me the correlation between any two adjacent pixels, in the horiz, vertical or diagonal direction.

Basically this is what I mean:For statistical analysis of an 
encrypted image: This is shown by a test of the 
correlation between two adjacent pixels in plain image 
and encrypted image. We randomly select 2000 pairs of 
two-adjacent pixels (in vertical, horizontal, and 
diagonal direction) each from plain images and ciphered 
images, and calculate the correlation coefficients,
respectively by the following: 
corr coeff=covariance(x,y)/variance(x)^0.5*variance(y)^0.5

where x and y are the grey scale values of the two neighboring pixels. And each of these is summed over all the pixels in the image

Comment: Please be more precise on the issue you encounter and show us what you have got so far.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "horiz, vertical and diagonal correlation coeff's". Is each of those coefficients a single number, or a vector? How do you define them?

Comment: Do you mean the correlation of the pixel intensity changes along x and y axis?

Comment: This sounds a bit too specific for there to be a matlab command. But it's not hard to write a script yourself, especially since you know the steps.